# HyperLogLog Implementation on Redis Not Recognized

Tags: python, redis, redis-py, hyperloglog

I'm trying to run a simple code here which simply inserts a value into a key using the PFADD operation but I get this error:

> ResponseError: unknown command 'PFADD'

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r.pfadd("k", 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4,)
```

- Python version: 2
- Pandas version: 0.19.0
- Redis Version: 2.10.5`

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue a `r.execute_command("PFADD", "key", 1, 2, 3)` to see if your server supports the command.

If this command runs ok, then the issue is with `redis-py`.

#### Edit

http://redis.io/commands/pfadd was added in Redis 2.8.9, your version is older than this.

You probably can do your stuff using http://redis.io/commands/sadd, which is supported in early versions. Check this link and try the `set` commands. They are slower in counting members, but are deterministic.

Comment: tried that, but didn't work either. It used to work fine until that one fine day it just stopped.

Comment: If this doesn't work, go to shell of your machine, issue `redis-cli`, then inside type `info`. One of first lines of output will be `redis_version:`. This line should have a listed value greater than or equal to `2.8.9`.

Comment: looks like it is 2.6.9